# Change file permissions in PHP for both Linux and Windows servers

Tags: php, linux, windows, unix, file-permissions

I have a PHP function that changes the file permissions of a directory recursively and it works perfectly on our Linux production and staging servers, but on our local development machines which is on a Windows OS, I see this on the Apache logs although I don't see any errors on the front-end:

> 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This is my function:

```php
function fixFilePermissions() {
  exec('chmod -R 775 '.TMP_DOC_DIR);
}
```

Is there a way to change this function so that it works on both Linux and Windows servers?

Comment: Have you tried with the PHP built-in chmod function directly? (I honestly don't know if it will make any difference): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Indeed, chmod does not exist on Windows.  That is why you want to use native PHP modules or code if you want your code to work on both.  You could check for the OS, and call chmod on linux, and the equivalent (?) on Windows